# Removing brackets from a DataFrame column when exporting to CSV

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a column with values like this:

```
columnA
[12,4352,545]
[123123,5436,665]
[234,646,5747]
```

And when I write the DataFrame containing this column to a CSV, I want to remove the brackets around each array in the column. I've tried `str.replace` and `str.strip`, but the braces are never removed. I've also tried converting them all to tuples and then removing the parentheses instead, to no avail.

Comment: is your column string- or list- valued?

Comment: @QuangHoang Each entry in the column is a separate array, so I believe list-valued.

Answer (score 1):

Try, if your values are list instead of strings:

```
 df['colA'].astype(str).str.strip('[|]')
```

MVCE:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'colA':[[1,2],[3,4]]})
df
```

Output:

```
   colA
0  [1, 2]
1  [3, 4]
```

Convert list to string and strip characters.

```
df['colA'].astype(str).str.strip('[|]')
```

Output:

```
0    1, 2
1    3, 4
Name: colA, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend a different delimiter than comma.  You can use whatever you want though.

#### ScottBoston's Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'colA':[[1,2],[3,4]]})
```

---

#### `applymap`

```
#                       The Delimiter ▼
df.assign(colA=df.colA.map(lambda x: '|'.join(map(str, x))))
  colA
0  1|2
1  3|4
```